# Gridster with Highcharts, make specific Chart smaller and recalculate

Tags: highcharts, responsive-design, gridster

i am building a dashboard with gridster and highcharts.
If i resize the window and a widget with a highchart is bigger than the window, i want to resize it to make it smaller and gridster should recalculate the positions of the others.
I tried this code to make a widget and its highchart smaller if its bigger than the windows width:

```
$( ".dashboard > li" ).each(function()
        {
            var chart = $(this).children('div');

//          console.log(' Window: ' + width);
            console.log(chart);
            if(chart.width() > width)
            {
                //alert('hier');
//              $(this).css('width',width + 'px');
                $(this).css('background-color','red');
                chart.width(width);
                chart.highcharts().reflow();
            }
        });
```

but nothing happens.

If i resize the widgets and its highcharts manually, the main grid is still bigger than the window, because it doesnt recalcualte.

Please help me with that.

Update1: 
Positioning-Problem

So now i've made it in this way: If the screensize is unter a limit, all widgets get the same size and will be pushed to the first row by setting data-col=1 with jquery. Now a new problem occurs: The pushed widgets are overlapping the others. I guess gridster isnt recalcualting this stuff. How do i force him to recalcualte positions? "avoid_overlapped_widgets: true" isn't working

Comment: This was my question to "make a specific chart smaller":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630868/highcharts-select-a-single-chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its done!!!! :D

SOLUTION:

I am calculation the last row with:

```
var row = 0;
var lastRow = 0;
$( ".dashboard > li" ).each(function()
            {
                rowe = parseInt($(this).attr('data-row'));
                if(row < rowe)
                {
                    row = rowe;
                    lastElement = $(this);
                }
                lastRow = parseInt($(this).attr('data-row'));
            });
```

and then I moved my all my widgets to the first column and the last row

```
if(parseInt($(this).attr('data-col')) > 1)
{
   $(".gridster ul").data('gridster').move_widget($(this), 1, lastRow);
 }
```

move_widget is a function made here: [Move Gridster Widgets programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429388/move-gridster-widgets-programmatically)

Thanks for answering

[CLOSED]

Comment: OH nooo, he does not do this in Android

Comment: ok Android didn't load the fully javascript. After another try it works

Answer (score 0):

Call  window resize function while you change width in gridster. Use highchart calling div's width in percentage. don't use fixed width.

```
 $(window).resize();
```

Comment: So now i've made it in this way:
If the screensize is unter a limit, all widgets get the same size and will be pushed to the first row by setting data-col=1 with jquery.
Now a new problem occurs:
The pushed widgets are overlapping the others. I guess gridster isnt recalcualting this stuff. How do i force him to recalcualte positions?
"avoid_overlapped_widgets: true" isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You can set width as 100% on chart container (in CSS) or call [setSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize) when you resize chart.